# pandas mask change value where condition true and false

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, mask

I have a matrix of values. I want to rank the values in the columns and then set top ranked values to 1 and others to zero.

I have tried to do this using `nlargest`, `head` but the only solution I can figure out is to apply `mask` twice.

My solution is below, but is there a smarter way to do this?

many thanks

John

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3),
                   (4, 5, 6),
                   (7, 8, 9),
                   (11, 21, 31),
                   (41, 51, 31),
                   (71, 51, 61),
                   (71, 81, 91)],
                  columns=('value_1','value_2','value_3'))
```

|  | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 3 | 11 | 21 | 31 |
| 4 | 41 | 51 | 31 |
| 5 | 71 | 51 | 61 |
| 6 | 71 | 81 | 91 |

```
N = 3 # arbitrary cut off
df = df.rank(ascending=False, axis=0, method='min')
df.mask(df > N, 0, inplace=True)
df.mask(df > 0, 1, inplace=True) # i.e. values not previously masked
```

Resulting `df`

|  | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the boolean values and then use astype

```
(~(df.rank(ascending=False, axis=0, method='min') > N)).astype(int)

   value_1  value_2  value_3
0        0        0        0
1        0        0        0
2        0        0        0
3        0        0        1
4        1        1        1
5        1        1        1
6        1        1        1
```

Comment: why to do negation? Directly, `((df.rank(ascending=False, axis=0, method='min') <= 3)).astype(int)`

Comment: @ggaurav you can do it that way as well. I was following the logic established in his questions: `> N` But technically `<=N` is the same as `>N`

Comment: thanks It_is_Chris and @ggaurav thanks for taking the time